# Limitations of apartment living

Tags: shower, safety

I'm disabled and live in a 55+ apartment. I need safety handles in my shower to help me step over an 8" lip to enter the shower.The maintenance manager won't put permanent metal bars for my safety unless I pay him $150 per safety handle. I just don't have that kind of money. And anything I add will stay if and when I move on.
So I bought some rubber and plastic suction cup handles for my tub/shower walls. One wall is made of smooth plastic tiles and the other wavy glass. The hold-on bar has 2 suction-cups that are flattened by using a lever on each cup, supposedly securing the whole handle to the suction cups on each side. I want the handle to be more permanent. I want to securely glue the handle to the shower walls and glass. What kind of glue is most likely to work with wavy glass and flat plastic stall walls?
Gorilla construction adhesive sort of worked for awhile. E6000 glue didn't work at all.

Comment: Best bet by far is if you can find wood studs behind the *plastic*. If they are metal studs then a bit harder to attach properly (but not impossible), and on the glass side much trickier because you don't want it to crack when drilling through it. Basic idea is to find studs, drill holes a little smaller than mounting screws, use screws through the grab bars and tile to mount to the wall *in the studs*. I'm more than a little surprised that a 55+ community would (a) have such high shower thresholds and (b) not already have grab bars *everywhere*.

Comment: Tell them that you would like them to deny your request ***in writing***. Inform them that if anything should happen that they would now be committing *gross* negligence. "is a lack of care that demonstrates reckless disregard for the safety or lives of others, which is so great it appears to be **a conscious violation** of other people's rights to safety." - Price isn't even on the table. They gave you the *go away* price that if you said yes they wouldn't mind. - If you were my tenant, these would be on the wall in 2h after you asked, free of charge, *no questions asked*.

Comment: *The maintenance manager* - call the *landlord* and tell them that their employee has ignored a safety concern. Or have someone else call up on your behalf and ask *double you tee eff* is going on here, and should we involve lawyers or are you going just put the freaking bars in?

Comment: A key, in my mind, is **55+ apartment**. That generally, to me, implies two things: 1 - no little kids running around, 2 - designed to let you age in place. Even without any disability whatsoever, "senior living" normally means: grab bars in all the typical places (essentially all over the bathroom), ramps everywhere as an alternative to steps, essentially very safety conscious because when older people fall they tend to get in big trouble, so you want to avoid the falls as much as possible. In addition, your disability *may* (I am not a lawyer) trigger ADA-compliance issues,

Comment: though that gets a bit complicated at times. And now I just realized I'm at that age - 56 this fall. Argh! I'm too young to be "old"!

Comment: $150 per, To me that seems a reasonable price to pay to have the job done properly.  see if you qualify for any alternative funding sources.

Comment: Where in the world do people get the notion that landlords are obliged to install special-needs equipment for tenants at their own expense? That's just plain hooey.

Comment: @kreemoweet  The idea on tenants getting special needs equipment at the expense of the property owner comes from the Americans with Disabilities Act.  I've used the ADA to get special needs accommodations from my employers before.  My requests cost them very little but they didn't want to do the work since it meant making some change or exception to company policy.  The ADA is really nothing special, there's all kinds of laws on making accommodations for people to keep them safe, the ADA merely expands the margins a bit to cover a wider portion of the population.